# What is cyclomatic complexity and how relevant it is today?

Tags: terminology, software-engineering

I have read that cyclomatic complexity is widely used, but critique on it exists
claimed that it is based on poor theoretical foundations and an
inadequate model of software development.

I have read [here](https://dspace.mit.edu/bitstream/handle/1721.1/47149/cyclomaticcomple00gill.pdf?sequence=1) page 10, second para

Comment: 1) Where have you read that? 2) If you want ot talk to practitioners, you should hit [softwareengineering.SE].

Comment: I have update the question with link. Is it purely Software Eng. question? I see you put it on hold?

Comment: I suggest you do a bit more research, then use that to narrow down your question.  I suspect you'll be able to get at least partial answers to your question in standard resources: see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity#Correlation_to_number_of_defects) and search on the Software Engineering site.  For instance, your question seems to be answered at https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/290405/34181 and https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/149010/34181 and https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/96934/34181.

Comment: See also https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cyclomatic-complexity.  Anyway, this site works best when you do a significant amount of research before asking, and show us in the question what research you've done and what you've found so far and use it to articulate a more narrowly focused question.  This [helps you get better answers](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).  "What is cyclomatic complexity?" is answered in standard resources.  "How relevant is it?" seems like a matter of opinion, which isn't a great fit here; see our [help/dont-ask].